# Assigning a Task to a User From Lookup In Another List

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, tasks

I have a list with several fields, one being an ID (single line text) and another an Approver (person/group). I then have another list where the ID is the source for a lookup. What I would like to happen is when an item is created in the second list an approval workflow is created with the task assigned to the person/group associated with the ID. I know that a person/group field isn't supported as a lookup field, but is there any other way I can retrieve the required reference to the user to assign the task?

Is there any way I can copy something from the person/group into another field as a string, and then use that as a lookup to retrieve it in the second list?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicate the value of the Approver column in the first list to the second list. Open the second list, choose the column called 'ID' (which is a lookup of ID from the first list) and choose the field 'Approver' to be viewed as well.